# JavaEE Transaction rollback

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have got a problem with transaction rollback.

I need to first insert a user into the database, and then insert into another table some kind of log of who inserted the user.
If there is an exception when inserting this log-message, the whole transaction should be rolled back (i.e. user needs to be removed again).

The .ear is deployed on Wildfly 8.1, persistence is achieved through Hibernate with MySQL.

My class looks like this

```
@Stateless
@Remote(AdministratorBiznesowyService.class)
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public class AdministratorBiznesowyServiceBean implements AdministratorBiznesowyService {
```

The method looks like this

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public void insertUser(String userSessionId, User user) throws AdministratorBiznesowyException {

  checkPermission(userSessionId);
  try {
    userBusiness.insertUser(user);
    log.insertLog(
        authenticationObjectBusiness.getUserIdForSessionId(userSessionId),
        LogEnum.CREATE, user);
  } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    ServerLogModule.logActionError(Messages
      .getErrorMessage("server.authorization.noPermission"));
    throw new AdministratorBiznesowyException();
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    ServerLogModule.logActionError(Messages
      .getErrorMessage("server.exception"));
    throw new AdministratorBiznesowyException();
  }*/
```

}

The insertUser implementation in userBusiness:

```
@Override
public void insertUser(User user) throws   AdministratorBiznesowyException {
try {
  UserEntity userEntity = adminConvertUtils.convertUserToEntity(user);
  userEntityFacade.create(userEntity);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  throw new AdministratorBiznesowyException();
 }
}
```

And my log.insertLog currently for test-purposes just throws an exception.

```
throw new LogException();
```

and its implementation is like this:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class LogException extends RuntimeException {
```

AdministratorBiznesowyException:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class AdministratorBiznesowyException extends CommunicationException {
```

CommunicationException:

```
public class CommunicationException extends Exception {
```

So now, when I successfully call insertUser and directly after that get an exception, the new user still gets added to the database (I check through MySQL Workbench).

What else can I do to get this to rollback?
If any other code is needed, please comment, thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the exception that bubbles out of the transactional method is NOT the LogException you marked to rollback the transaction, it is the AdministratorBiznesowyException. What does that exception look like?

Comment: Added exception implementations to the question

Comment: I think I marked everything with rollback=true that I could, but still it does not help..

Comment: You use `@Remote`? Note that `@Transactional` can not be proxied to a different business-level servers. A second transaction is started after the insertion of user.